# Updating excel with vba to sql server, update or insert query doesn't actually update data

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba, excel

So I have fixed my initial problem. However, now my data isn't actually updated by the data in the excel file. Instead, the #temp table never takes on the value of the excel file but keeps the original data that is inputted. How do I make sure the data is coming from the excel file? Right now I am inputting the data from the original table just purely to keep the structure. Then I want to replace that with the new data on the temp table. Then replace the data on the table with the temp table data.

```
 Dim cmd As Object
    Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    Dim beforeSQL As String

    With CN

    .Execute " Select * Into #temp1 from dim.DepartmentLeader"
    End With

    Dim level As Long

     level = CN.BeginTrans

    cmd.CommandType = 1             ' adCmdText

    ' Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim rst As Object
    Set rst = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    With rst
        Set .ActiveConnection = CN
        .Source = "SELECT * FROM  #temp1"
        .CursorLocation = 3         ' adUseClient
        .LockType = 4               ' adLockBatchOptimistic
        .CursorType = 0             ' adOpenForwardOnly
        .Open



        ' Column mappings

        Dim tableFields(8) As Integer
        Dim rangeFields(1000) As Integer

        Dim exportFieldsCount As Integer
        exportFieldsCount = 0

        Dim col As Integer
        Dim index As Integer
        Dim lastRow As String
        Dim copyRange As String



        lastRow = LastRowInOneColumn()

        For col = 0 To .Fields.Count - 1
            index = Application.Match(.Fields.Item(col).Name, Range("A1:H249").Rows(1), 0)

            If index > 0 Then
     exportFieldsCount = exportFieldsCount + 1
                tableFields(exportFieldsCount) = col
                rangeFields(exportFieldsCount) = index
            End If
        Next

       If exportFieldsCount = 0 Then
            ExportRangeToSQL = 1
            GoTo ConnectionEnd
        End If

        ' Fast read of Excel range values to an array
        ' for further fast work with the array

        Dim arr As Variant
        arr = Range(Cells(1, 13).Value).Value

        ' The range data transfer to the Recordset

        Dim row As Long
        Dim rowCount As Long
        rowCount = UBound(arr, 1)

        Dim val As Variant

        For row = 2 To rowCount
            .AddNew
            For col = 1 To exportFieldsCount
                val = arr(row, rangeFields(col))

                Debug.Print row

                If IsEmpty(val) Then

                Else

                    .Fields(tableFields(col)) = val

                End If
            Next
        Next


.UpdateBatch

       End With

 With CN

.Execute "update dim.DepartmentLeader set " & _
       "AUDescriptions = #temp1.AUDescriptions, " & _
        "Dim.DepartmentLeader.Status = #temp1.Status, " & _
         "dim.DepartmentLeader.Pillar = #temp1.Pillar," & _
          "dim.DepartmentLeader.L1 = #temp1.L1, " & _
           "dim.DepartmentLeader.L2 = #temp1.L2," & _
           "dim.DepartmentLeader.L3 = #temp1.L3," & _
           "dim.DepartmentLeader.L4 = #temp1.L4 " & _
           "FROM dim.DepartmentLeader Inner Join #temp1 On dim.DepartmentLeader.DepartmentNumber= #temp1.DepartmentNumber " & _
  "WHERE dim.DepartmentLeader.DepartmentNumber = #temp1.DepartmentNumber " & _
  "IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 " & _
  "insert into dim.DepartmentLeader (dim.DepartmentLeader.DepartmentNumber, dim.DepartmentLeader.AUDescriptions, dim.DepartmentLeader.Status, dim.DepartmentLeader.Pillar,dim.DepartmentLeader.L1, dim.DepartmentLeader.L2,dim.DepartmentLeader.L3,dim.DepartmentLeader.L4)" & _
       " SELECT * FROM #temp1 "

        End With
rst.Close
    Set rst = Nothing



ConnectionEnd:

    CN.CommitTrans
```

Comment: How do you know it doesn't take on the value? How are you inspecting it? Your update is pretty complex - maybe the issue is there. I suggest you use SQL Profiler to observe the database activity, OR use the debugger to confirm that it runs the update.

Comment: I know it runs the update because I added a '0' to the end of one of the fields like L1+0. Then I saw it in the actual database so suddenly all of my L1 fields were 'xyz0' etc. A moment of Huzzah was killed later when I tried changing the actual data in the excel sheet....and was not met with a change in the database

Comment: So... you changed a field in `dim.DepartmentLeader` and saw that reflected in your Excel? Remember we only know what you explain to use and it's still not clear how this works. Can I suggest four things to assist troubleshooting: 1. Hard code your update to set a column to a hard coded value - does that work? 2. Hard code your update to set a specific row (i.e. don't join to temp) - does that work? 3. Add a 'date last updated' column to your table  and populate it (which is pretty much a vital piece of information in a dimension anyway). 4. Use SQL Profiler

Comment: I am sorry for not being more clear. I had done steps 1 and 2 and confirmed they worked. However, thank you for recommending step 3, now I know that some of the instances are updating, but not all of them. I made a new row called DateChanged and some are being populated with 8/18/2015 others are NULL. I assume it is most likely something to do with the If statement or such as.

Comment: If data is not being updated when expected, that implies that the join on `DepartmentNumber ` is failing. It might be that the round trip through Excel is subtly changing the value. I'm still trying to understand your code. Are you loading a copy of DimDepartmentLeader into Excel then writing that back _twice_ into the temp table? I suggest one more thing: change the temp table to a real table and inspect the data.

Comment: I see where the code looks like I am copying into the temp table twice. The first time it does copy the original table into the temp table purely for the formatting of the fields.. The second select, chooses to use the temp table to be filled with the record set. Then it either updates or inserts the data. I can try using an actual table, that way I can see how the data is being translated.

Comment: Yes - try a real table. I still don't understand why you are filling the table twice. If you only want to fill it once, add `WHERE 1=0` to the very first execute then it will create an empty table with the correct columns.

Comment: Long over due. Your advice was very helpful. In the end, I used a merge clause instead. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `UpdateBatch` with a `adOpenForwardOnly` cursor. You should only be using `UpdateBatch` with a `Keyset` or `Static` cursor only.  See this MSDN article for more information: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675283(v=vs.85).aspx

```
With rst
    Set .ActiveConnection = cn
    .Source = "SELECT * FROM  ##temp1"
    .CursorLocation = 3         ' adUseClient
    .LockType = 4               ' adLockBatchOptimistic

    'Use a Keyset cursor in prep for using UpdateBatch
    .CursorType = 1             ' adOpenKeyset 

    ......
    ......

End With
```

Alternatively, you could consider using `rst.Update` for each individual recordset in the loop.